# Category Icon on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I am using custom post types "listings" and I have a category called "type" and 3 sub cats, "available", "pending", "sold".

I want to display an image/icon on each post in the loop (not the single-listings.php) but the archive view, that corresponds to it's category. Take a look at woothemes' Estate for an example. They have an image over the featured image that says "on show".

Any thoughts on how to go about this? or a plugin that might do something similar?

thanks!

I found this code reference:

```
 <?php $cats = get_the_category(); echo $cats[0]->category_name;?>">
```

And then it said to style using the category as a class in the css, but no go. It returns nothing - wondering if custom post type cats need to be handled differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the conditional with `in_category`.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category

For example after your loop:

```
<?php if (in_category('type')) { ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/images/custom.gif" alt="" class="customicons"/>
```

Comment: receiving an error code on the above.

Comment: The code is not exact because I do not know your specifics, but an example. It is also missing a closing `}`

Comment: Will this work within the custom post type taxonomy? For instance my CPT is Listing with a taxonomy of Status (which includes Available, Pending, Sold)

Comment: It might I'm not sure, if not check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/taxonomy_exists